# foreach loop in Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$marks=array(
array(a1,a2,a3),
array(b1,b2,b3),
array(c1,c2,c3)
 );
```

so i want this in foreach loop

example

```
echo "text-start".$marks[0]."text11".$marks[1]."text22".$marks[2]."text-end";
```

and result to be:

> text-start**a1**text11**a2**text22**a3**text-end
>
> text-start**b1**text11**b2**text22**b3**text-end
>
> text-start**c1**text11**c2**text22**c3**text-end

i tried this  but it show **a1a2a3**  **b1b2b3**
and i cant add text between them

```
for($r=0;$r<count($marks);$r++)
{
    for($c=0;$c<count($marks[$r]);$c++)
    {
        echo $marks[$r][$c]."test";
    }
    echo "111<br>";
}
```

Comment: where is your attempt with the `foreach()` loop?

Comment: for($r=0;$r<count($marks);$r++)
{
 for($c=0;$c<count($marks[$r]);$c++)
 {

  echo $marks[$r][$c]."test";
 }
 echo "111<br>";
}

Comment: please do no post code in comments. Add it to your question.

Comment: Well, that's not a foreach loop, that's a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basics...

```
foreach($marks as $marky_marks){
    echo "text-start".$marky_marks[0]."text11".$marky_marks[1]."text22".$marky_marks[2]."text-end";
}
```